# Angular2 : @Output and Event Emitter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to follow this : http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Here is what i have :

account.component.html

```
<app-messagerie (onViewMessages)="handleOnViewMessages($event)"></app-messagerie>
<a (click)="onViewMessagerie(users.id)">My messages</a>
```

account.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onViewMessages = new EventEmitter();

...

onViewMessagerie(id){
  this.onViewMessages.emit(id)
}
```

messagerie.component.ts

```
handleOnViewMessages(id){
  console.log(id);
  console.log('ahah');
}
```

But nothing happen when i click.

Am i missing something, or doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You have to set `(onViewMessages)` on your `AccountComponent` selector. Add complete code that you have tried so far and someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up parent and child components. `Account component` is the parent, so it should hold `handleOnViewMessages()` method.
`messagerie component` is the child, it should have @Output decorator to communicate with the parent via event emitter.

**account.compoent.html**

```
<app-messagerie (onViewMessages)="handleOnViewMessages($event)"></app-messagerie>
```

**account.compoent.ts**

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

....

handleOnViewMessages(event){
  console.log(event);
  console.log('ahah');
}
```

**messagerie.component.ts**

```
 @Output() onViewMessages = new EventEmitter();

...

onViewMessagerie(id){
  this.onViewMessages.emit(id)
}
```

**messagerie.html**

```
<a (click)="onViewMessagerie(users.id)">My messages</a>
```

You will though need to manage user.id as I am unable to see the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is working great! But my button calling onViewMessagerie is in account.html and not in messagerie.html

Comment: Is the logic is that from account you click a button and all messages are displayed?

Comment: Look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RJ0QcDuLLatiwy9hKVQr?p=preview

Comment: thx a loot for your plunker. I'll take a look and let you know how i'll manage to do this in my app. thanks !

Comment: Output is when the child needs to send a change status/info/data to the parent. Input is parent's way to set child property.